# SQL Server 2012 timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql-server

We have a thin C# application with SQL server 2012 Enterprise Edition . Database size is 23GB . The server has 32 GB RAM and 2.4 Ghz Xeon processor, with 8 cores.

We have one user table with more than 6 Million Records.

1. When we do loadtest with 1000 users, application is giving connection timeout with simple query like.

   `SELECT Field1, Field2, ….. FROM dbo.Users WHERE Email = 'xyz@gmail.com'`
2. CPU usage goes to 100% and continuous to 100%.
3. It logs the error like timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

We have to optimize the application. We have removed duplicate index and added missing indexes.

Here's what we have done so far:

1. **Run SQL trace of long running queries and deadlocks**: This shows no deadlocks at the times of the problems, and long running queries all coincide with our timeout errors, but look to be a side effect, and not the cause. Queries that are very basic that typically return instantly end up taking 30, 60 or 120 seconds to run at times. This happens for a few minutes then everything picks up and works fine after that.
2. **Reindexed all the tables again.**
3. **Restarted SQL Server.**
4. **Change Connection Timeout Value from 300 to 600.**

Please let me know some ideas on what to troubleshoot next.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is DBA stuff, so try the DBA site.

Comment: do you have an index where Email field is the first indexed field.  Have you also checked the query execution plan for the query, and how much work it would need to do - also what does your loadtest do?  How frequently are the 1000 users having to execute a query - are you simply overloading the server?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. On careful inspection, we found one of the problem you mentioned about overloading the server. We changed the load test pattern and got improvement. We also found some hardware limitation and improve that as well which helped us solve problem for even more number of user load.